# Как выбрать из MySQL то, что еще не выбрано

Tags: php, mysql

Есть в базе 3 таблицы:
Студент, Препод и Индивид
Индивид - содержит данные фио паспорт адрес
Студент и Препод имеют поля - ссылки на записи в индивиде.

Как при создании нового препода или студента выбрать из `MySQL` только тех индивидов, которые еще не заняты, как нить 1 запросом можно? Просто 1 запрос и все дела, без кучи кода

Студ: stud_id, email,pass,**ind_id**

Препод: pr_id,kaf_id,**ind_id**

Индивид: **ind_id**, fio, passport, adress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вам нужно что-то вроде

```
select * 
from individ i 
where i.ind_id not in (select s.ind_id from stud s) and
      i.ind_id not in (select p.ind_id from prepod p)
```

Comment: Можно еще:

    select * 
     from 
      individ i 
     where 
      i.ind_id not in 
    (select s.ind_id from stud s union select p.ind_id from prepod p)


но суть не в этом.